# Visualising many variables in one plot

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'd like to show how the values of certain variables (~ 15) change over time, but I'd also like to show how the variables differ from each other in each year. So I created this plot:

[image]

But even when changing the colour scheme or adding different line/shape types this looks messy. Is there a better way to visualise this kind of data?

Test data with R code:

```
structure(list(Var = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 
    2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 
    1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 
    2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 
    2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 
    1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 
    2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 
    1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 
    2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 
    2011L, 2015L), Val = c(25.6, 22.93, 20.82, 24.1, 24.5, 29, 
    25.55, 24.5, 24.52, 20.73, 25.8, 25.5, 29.5, 27.7, 25.1, 
    25, 24.55, 26.75, 25, 30.5, 27.25, 25.1, 22.4, 27.07, 26, 
    29, 27.2, 24.2, 23, 24.27, 27.68, 27, 30.5, 28.1, 24.9, 23.75, 
    22.75, 27.25, 25, 29, 28.45, 24, 20.25, 17.07, 24.45, 25, 
    28.5, 26.75, 24.9, 21.25, 20.65, 25.1, 24.5, 26.5, 25.35, 
    23.5, 21.93, 26.5, 24.5, 29, 29.1, 26.4, 28.1, 23.75, 26.5, 
    28.05, 27, 30.5, 25.65, 23.3, 23.25, 24.57, 26.07, 27.5, 
    28.85, 27.7, 22, 23.43, 26.88, 27, 30.5, 29.25, 28.1, 23, 
    23.8, 28.32, 27, 29.5, 29.15, 27.6)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 84L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L), na.action = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 11L, 12L, 33L, 34L, 42L, 43L, 51L, 52L, 60L, 61L, 76L, 77L, 
85L, 86L, 93L, 94L, 102L, 103L), .Names = c("2", "3", "11", "12", 
"33", "34", "42", "43", "51", "52", "60", "61", "76", "77", "85", 
"86", "93", "94", "102", "103"), class = "omit"), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Var", 
"Year", "Val"))
```

Comment: Can you post the data? It's easy enough to find roughly similar examples, but to keep the thread tied together, people having the same sandbox to play in would help. Also, what's the significance of the green zone?

Comment: See also suggestions in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126480/color-and-line-thickness-recommendations-for-line-plots

Comment: @NickCox Sure, should have thought of that earlier! I left out the green zone as it's not essential (it only shows the range of values which is considered "sufficient")

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Fortuitously or otherwise, your example is of optimal size (up to 7 values for each of 15
groups) first, to show that there is a problem graphically; and second, to allow other and
fairly simple solutions. The graph is of a kind often called **spaghetti** by people in
different fields, although it's not always clear whether that term is meant as affectionate
or abusive. (The term spaghetti was used by Gene Zelazny in 1985, but may well be much older
yet.) The graph does show the collective or family behaviour of all the groups, but it is
fairly hopeless at showing the detail to be explored.

One standard alternative is just to show the separate groups in separate panels, but that in
turn can make precise group-to-group comparisons difficult; each group is separated from its
context of the other groups.

So why not combine both ideas: a separate panel for each group, but also show the other
groups as backdrop? This hinges crucially on highlighting the group which is in focus and on
downplaying the others, which is easy enough in this example given some use of line colour,
thickness etc. In other examples, marker or point symbol choices might be natural instead.

[image]

In this case, details of possible practical or scientific importance or interest are
highlighted:

1. We only have one value for A and M.
2. We don't have all values for all given years in all other cases.
3. Some groups plot high, some low, and so forth.

I won't attempt an interpretation here: the data are anonymous, but that is the researcher's
concern in any case.

Depending on what is easy or possible in your software, there is scope for changing small
details here, such as whether axis labels and titles are repeated (there are simple
arguments both for and against).

The larger issue is how far this strategy will work more generally. The number of groups is
the major driver, more so than the number of points in each group. Roughly speaking, the
approach might work up to about 25 groups (a 5 x 5 display, say): with more groups, not only
do the graphs become smaller and more difficult to read, but even the researcher loses the
inclination to scan all the panels. If there were hundreds (thousands, ...) of groups, it
would usually be essential to select a small number of groups to show. Some mix of criteria
such as selecting some "typical" and some "extreme" panels would be needed; that should be
driven by project goals and some idea of what makes sense for each dataset. Another approach
that can be efficient is to emphasize a small number of series in each panel. So, if there
were 25 broad groups, each broad group could be shown with all others as backdrop.
Alternatively, there could be some averaging or other summarization. Using (e.g.) principal
or independent components might also be a good idea.

Although the example calls for line plots, the principle is naturally much general. Examples
could be multiplied, scatter plots, model diagnostic plots, etc.

**Similar but not identical ideas**

Cleveland (1985, pp.74, 203, 205, 268) shows graphs in which summary curves
for groups are repeated with data shown separately for each group.
(Note: these graphs do not appear in Cleveland 1994.)

Wallgren et al. (1996, pp.47, 69) use the same idea.

Cleveland, W.S. 1985. *Elements of Graphing Data.* Monterey, CA: Wadsworth.

Cleveland, W.S. 1994. *Elements of Graphing Data.* Summit, NJ: Hobart Press.

Wallgren, A., B. Wallgren, R. Persson, U. Jorner, and J.-A. Haaland.
1996. *Graphing Statistics and Data: Creating Better Charts.* Newbury
Park, CA: SAGE.

Zelazny (1985 and later editions) has a different twist:

Zelazny, G. 1985. *Say It With Charts: The Executive's Guide to Successful Presentations.*
Homewood, IL: Dow Jones-Irwin. See p.39 for a graph with four panels: series A compared in
turn with series B, C, D, E. See also p.111.

Same pages in 4th edition: Zelazny, G. 2001. *Say It With Charts: The Executive's Guide to
Visual Communication.* New York: McGraw-Hill. See p.39 for a graph with four panels: series
A compared in turn with series B, C, D, E. See also p.111.

**Direct examples [others are most welcome]**

Koenker, R. 2005. *Quantile Regression.* Cambridge: Cambridge University
Press. See pp.12-13.

Carr, D.B. and Pickle, L.W. 2010. *Visualizing Data Patterns with Micromaps.* Boca Raton,
FL: CRC Press. See p.85.

Cox, N.J. 2010. Graphing subsets. *Stata Journal* 10: 670-681.

Yau, N. 2013. *Data Points: Visualization That Means Something.*
Indianapolis, IN: John Wiley. See p.224.

Rougier, N.P., Droettboom, M. and Bourne, P.E. 2014.
Ten simple rules for better figures.
*PLOS Computational Biology* 10(9): e1003833.
doi:10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003833
[link here](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003833)

Schwabish, J.A. 2014. An economist's guide to visualizing data. *Journal
of Economic Perspectives* 28: 209-234.

Knaflic, C.N. 2015. *Storytelling with Data: A Data Visualization Guide
for Business Professionals.* Hoboken, NJ: Wiley. See p.233.

Unwin, A. 2015. *Graphical Data Analysis with R.* Boca Raton, FL: CRC
Press. See pp.121, 217.

Berinato, S. 2016.
*Good Charts: The HBR Guide to Making Smarter, More Persuasive Data Visualizations.*
Boston, MA: Harvard Business Review Press. See p.74.

Cairo, A. 2016.
*The Truthful Art: Data, Charts, and Maps for Communication.*
San Francisco, CA: New Riders. See p.211

Camões, J. 2016. *Data at Work: Best Practices for Creating Effective Charts
and Information Graphics in Microsoft Excel*. San Francisco, CA: New
Riders. See p.354.

Standage, T. 2016. *Go Figure: The Economist Explains: Things You Didn't Know You Didn't Know.* London: Profile Books. See p.177.

Wickham, H. 2016. *ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis.* Cham: Springer.
See p.157.

Schwabish, J. 2017.  *Better Presentations: A Guide for Scholars, Researchers, and Wonks.*  New York: Columbia University Press. See p.98.

Kriebel, A. and Murray, E. 2018. *#MakeoverMonday: Improving How We Visualize and Analyze
Data, One Chart at a Time.* Hoboken, NJ: John Wiley. See p.303.

Grant, R. 2019. *Data Visualization: Charts, Maps, and Interactive Graphics.*
Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press. See p.52.

Koponen, J. and Hildén, J. 2019.
*The Data Visualization Handbook.*
Espoo: Aalto ARTS Books. See p.101.

Tufte, E.R. 2020. *Seeing with Fresh Eyes: Meaning, Space, Data, Truth.*
Cheshire, CT: Graphics Press. See p.26 [original work by John Burn-Murdoch, but showing 0 on logarithmic scale (!) and alphabetical order by countries, which could be tuned]

Note: The graph was created in Stata. `subsetplot` must be installed first with `ssc inst subsetplot`. Data were copied and pasted from R and value labels were defined to show years as `90 95 00 05 10 15`. The main command is

```
subsetplot connected Val Year, by(Var) c(L) lcolor(gs12) backdrop(line) xtitle("") combine(imargin(small)) subset(lcolor(blue) mcolor(blue))
```

Comment: +1, wonderful, is there an R or SAS function that is able to do this type of chart? It's really great.

Comment: I really like this idea! Just wondering about the best way to plot this in R using ggplot2. I'll just wait a bit before I accept the answer, hope that's fine.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about how to do anything in SAS. Surely anything Stata can do, R can do as well or better, or so its users keep telling me....

Comment: @NickCox Not a problem at all, I figured it out, it looks really good and is perfect for my purpose.

Comment: @NickCox, two more references are 1. [The Elements of Graphing Data by W.S. Cleveland](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0963488414?keywords=elements%20of%20graphing%20data&qid=1453300848&ref_=sr_1_1&sr=8-1).A new book,  2. [Storytelling with Data: A Data Visualization Guide for Business Professionals by Cole Nussbaumer Knaflic](http://www.amazon.com/Storytelling-Data-Visualization-Business-Professionals/dp/1119002257/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1453300881&sr=1-1&keywords=storytelling+with+data).This book (#2) has a case study chapter called "Strategies for avoiding the spaghetti graph".

Comment: @forecaster Thanks, but Knaflic is already in my references. I have been through both of Cleveland's books and I don't think there is any example there of precisely this idea. There are numerous examples of the "small multiples" strategy. The point is not to document cases in which subsets are plotted separately (long since a standard idea), but to document cases in which each subset is plotted separately, **with the other subsets as backdrop or substrate**. I'd be happy to amend the references if you can supply pages with examples of the kind.

Comment: Nevertheless Cleveland had a similar idea in 1985, now documented.

Answer (score 26):

As a complement to Nick's answer, here's some R code for making a similar plot using simulated data:

```
library(ggplot2)

get_df <- function(label="group A", n_obs=10, drift=runif(1)) {
    df <- data.frame(time=seq(1, n_obs), label=label)
    df$y <- df$time * drift + cumsum(rnorm(n_obs))
    return(df)
}
df_list <- lapply(sprintf("group %s", toupper(letters[1:9])),
                  function(label) { get_df(label) })
df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
df$label2 <- df$label

p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=y, group=label2)) +
      geom_line(size=0.9, alpha=0.8,
                data=df[, c("time", "y", "label2")], color="grey") +
      geom_line(size=1.1, color="black") +
      ylab("") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.border=element_blank()) +
      theme(strip.background=element_blank()) +
      facet_wrap(~ label))
p
ggsave("example_facet.png", p, width=10, height=8)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: There is also [gghighlight](https://github.com/yutannihilation/gghighlight) package available

Answer (score 11):

For those wanting to use a `ggplot2` approach in R consider the `facetshade` function in the package `extracat`.  This offers a general approach, not just for line plots.  Here is an example with scatterplots (from the foot of [this page](http://www.gradaanwr.net/content/ch10/)):

```
data(olives, package="extracat")
library(scales)
fs1 <- facetshade(data = olives,
                  aes(x = palmitic, y = palmitoleic), f = 
                      . ~ Area)
fs1 + geom_point(colour = alpha("black", 0.05)) +
      geom_point(data = olives, colour = "red") +
      facet_wrap(f=~Area, nrow=3) + 
          theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

---

EDIT: Using Adrian's simulated dataset from his earlier answer:

```
library(extracat)
facetshade(df, aes(x=time, y=y), f = .~label, bg.all = FALSE, 
            keep.orig = TRUE) +
           geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y, 
             group=orig.label),colour = alpha(1,0.3)) +
           geom_line(data=df, aes(colour=label), size = 1.2) 
           + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Another approach is to draw two separate layers, one for the background and one for the highlighted cases.  The trick is to draw the background layer using the dataset without the faceting variable.  For the olive oil dataset the code is:

```
data(olives, package="extracat")
ggplot(olives, aes(palmitic, palmitoleic)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Area, nrow=3) + 
  geom_point(data=olives %>% select(-Area), 
        colour=alpha("black", 0.05)) + 
  geom_point(data=olives, colour="red") + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: This seems like a nice general approach (+1), but the particular example is more relating to a different problem. A bunch of repeated scatter plots with differently highlighted regions is not gonna work for the question which is about time series.

Comment: @martin  Actually it is and that is also Adrian's solution.  Note that he uses two identical labelling variables so that one can be dropped in the background layer.  The coding idea is more obvious with the tidyverse notation below and, as so often, elegant formatting of graphics can mask the important parts of code.

`ggplot(df %>% select(-label), aes(x=time, y=y, group=label2)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.8, color="grey") + labs(y=NULL) +
  geom_line(data=df, color="red") + facet_wrap(~ label)`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution inspired by Ch. 11.3, the section on "Texas Housing Data", in [Hadley Wickham's Book on ggplot2](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book). Here I fit a linear model to each time series , take the residuals (which are centered around mean 0), and draw a summary line in a different color.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#works with dplyr version 0.4.3.9000 from Github (hadley/dplyr@4f2d7f8), or higher

df1 <- as.data.frame(list(Var = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
                                 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
                                 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
                                 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("A", 
                                                                                               "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
                                                                                               "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
               Year = c(2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 
                        2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 
                        1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 
                        2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 
                        2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 
                        1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 
                        2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 
                        2015L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 
                        1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 
                        2000L, 2004L, 2011L, 2015L, 1991L, 1993L, 1996L, 2000L, 2004L, 
                        2011L, 2015L), 
               Val = c(25.6, 22.93, 20.82, 24.1, 24.5, 29, 
                       25.55, 24.5, 24.52, 20.73, 25.8, 25.5, 29.5, 27.7, 25.1, 
                       25, 24.55, 26.75, 25, 30.5, 27.25, 25.1, 22.4, 27.07, 26, 
                       29, 27.2, 24.2, 23, 24.27, 27.68, 27, 30.5, 28.1, 24.9, 23.75, 
                       22.75, 27.25, 25, 29, 28.45, 24, 20.25, 17.07, 24.45, 25, 
                       28.5, 26.75, 24.9, 21.25, 20.65, 25.1, 24.5, 26.5, 25.35, 
                       23.5, 21.93, 26.5, 24.5, 29, 29.1, 26.4, 28.1, 23.75, 26.5, 
                       28.05, 27, 30.5, 25.65, 23.3, 23.25, 24.57, 26.07, 27.5, 
                       28.85, 27.7, 22, 23.43, 26.88, 27, 30.5, 29.25, 28.1, 23, 
                       23.8, 28.32, 27, 29.5, 29.15, 27.6)), 
               row.names = c(1L, 4L, 
                           5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                           21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 
                           36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
                           53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
                           68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
                           83L, 84L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 
                           100L, 101L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L), 
               na.action = structure(c(2L, 
                          3L, 11L, 12L, 33L, 34L, 42L, 43L, 51L, 52L, 60L, 61L, 76L, 77L, 
                          85L, 86L, 93L, 94L, 102L, 103L), 
                .Names = c("2", "3", "11", "12","33", "34", "42", "43", "51", "52", "60", 
                           "61", "76", "77", "85", "86", "93", "94", "102", "103"), class = "omit"), 
                class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Var","Year", "Val"))


df1 %>%
        group_by(Var) %>%
        do(mutate(.,resid = resid(lm(Val ~ Year, data=., na.action = na.exclude)))) %>%
        ggplot(aes(Year, resid)) +
        labs(y=paste0("Val "), x="Year") +
        geom_line(aes(group = Var), alpha = 1/5) +
        geom_line(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: The main idea here seems to be that you could add a summary curve of some kind to help the eye and mind. Agreed, but in your answer you could spell out the trade-off on shifting to mean (or reference level) 0 rather than leaving the original units and values. Subject-matter experts and/or clients might well think in terms of 24 or 28 or whatever values are. Naturally the data here are just a vehicle for the discussion but the point is highly general.