# Alternative Ways to Visualize Error/Uncertainty Line Plots for Multiple Data Sets

Tags: data-visualization

I'm trying to find an alternative way to visualize this data that may be more visually appealing and meaningful, but I'm not sure what other visualization I could use.

Each line represents a test run of different data sets, so I cannot lump them all together.  The % Error is the deviation from the mean of multiple monte carlo simulations for each data set, and the % Uncertainty is the 1-sigma standard deviation of the multiple monte carlo simulations for each data set. The variable $x$ is the simulated singnal-to-noise for each monte carlo test.

Is this the best I can do for visualizing this kind of data? My limitations are essentially the size of this plot.  I cannot add more plots per journal guidelines.

Edit: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190152/visualising-many-variables-in-one-plot) question address a similar problem, however most of these solutions require the use of multiple subplots.  While these are fine solutions, I am specifically looking for solutions that don't involve a large number of subplots.

[image]

Comment: What message are you trying to convey with your visualization?  Articulating a clear objective is the first consideration in any graphical design.  Characterizing the intended audience is also high up there.  Good solutions will vary radically according to these criteria.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visualising many variables in one plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190152/visualising-many-variables-in-one-plot)

Comment: @whuber These are performance measures for an algorithm, so the target audience is anybody who is interested in how well the algorithm performs as a function of x, notably, astronomers.

Comment: @NickCox Unfortunately not, as these solutions involve making more plots.  I could always use more plots, for each data set, and use something like a box plot, but the problem here is multiple datasets within one (or two in this case) plots

Comment: You can make each panel small and use the same total space. Otherwise: plot 12 series superimposed, plot 12 series juxtaposed, do both; there aren't any other choices that I know of unless you want to reduce the data to a summary or envelope.

Comment: @NickCox I should explain why I do not specifically like the multiple subplots method.  I will also be showing other similar plots as functions of y, and z, with similar numbers of tests.  Using multiple subplots for each of these would require a page full of subplots which could look overwhelming for the reader.  It doesn't quite provide a more elegant or meaningful solution to the problem, it only splits up the tests into multiple subplots.  But thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I think your criteria lead you back to your existing design as the only possible solution for you.